# how can I put a simple search form into the application layout in rails 2.3.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search, activerecord

I want to create a search form that appears in the header of my application (like the search in Stackoverflow).

T do this, I thought that I would put it into the layout for application.html.erb

But then what do I use as a route and action in the controller?

I want to pass the parameter to search through several ActiveRecords, probably using searchlogic.

Thanks.

This is very simple, may index with texticle later:

Here is my searches_controller.rb

```
  1 class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  2 
  3   def search
  4 
  5     @contacts_search = Contact.search(:first_name_like => params[:search])
  6 
  7 
  8 
  9   end
 10 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a SearchController.  I use ThinkingSphinx and it works fine, so no code to help there, but using a SearchController will allow you to route that way quite easily.

```
    <% form_tag search_search_path, :method => :get do %>
    <p id="search_header">
        <%= text_field_tag 'q', params[:q], {:size => 40} %>
        <%= submit_tag 'Search for Shops', :name => nil %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
```

Something like this.  I called my search method `search` in the `Search` controller... that's why the double search in the route.

Comment: Actually, the SearchesController should have a #show action, but same idea.

Comment: so I would be able to take the value params[:q] for example and run it through different searchlogic named_scopes?  I want to be able to search several active records for the same like field....

Comment: will this work in rails 2.3.x?  I haven't seen this double path search_search_path before, that is same as :controller => "search", :action => "search"?  or should I use "show" as @Francois

Comment: I can't speak to Searchlogic, but thinking sphinx makes it easy to use one search field with MANY models.  This sounds like what you want.  As for search action vs show action in the Search controller, it's preference. REST is a guideline and i doubt you'd be using your SAAS service for search anyways. not like this, so the name of the method, imo, is pure preference.

Comment: I see...doesn't thinking sphinx need to install or, in heroku's case, add an add on of some kind?...let me take a stabl, thanks, I think you set me in the right direction, not sure if I am doing the controller bit quite right....

Comment: Hello, I get this error, raking the routes now:  undefined local variable or method `search_search_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0xb552d374>)

Comment: I put my searches_controller.rb in my quesetion...perhspas I made it wrong

Comment: In heroku,  you are right, using Searchlogic is probably the way to go, or using one of their addons.  search_search_path, you need to add to  your routes file, map.resources :search, :member => :search, and you need to change params[:search] to params[:q] in your controller code, if you want it to match my posted answer's form.